# Find Latitude and Longitude with out using internet in my android phone

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I want to get latitude and longitude in my android application.
Please provide me a code for my android application to get latitude and longitude with out using internet..thanks

Comment: have u refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15192315/1915697 ???

Comment: What have you tried? There are tons of examples on the Internet with sample code. Or you could have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have GPS Provider and Network Provider.

Without internet you can use only [GPS Provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Here is snippets of code:

```
private final float MIN_DISTANCE = 6; // 6 meters

LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                          m_context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);


LocationListener listener = this;   

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates
           (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, MIN_DISTANCE, listener);

...

      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    /* your code  */
}
```