# get current location without internet - phonegap geolocation api for android

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to get the user's current location using phonegap Geolocation api, which says "Common sources of location information include Global Positioning System (GPS) and location inferred from network signals such as IP address, RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell IDs". I am able to properly get the location when internet is ON (irrespective of the state of GPS). 
Is there a way to get the location using triangulation when the internet is OFF or not accessible? (GPS might be ON or OFF)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A BIG **"NO"**! This is like cutting down hands and asking if I could clap now? GPS and NETWORK location providers are the only way to receive user device location.

**For *GPS* location** - you need GPS sensors to be ON.

**And for *NETWORK* location** you need to have internet connection ON, because in this case the location is calculated on the basis of Cell-Tower/Wifi-spot ID which is then sent to google servers (via internet) to fetch the location details of the respective Cell Tower or wifi spot. Google's location server have its own location approximation algorithms on the basis of which it tells your location.

So, there could be no way you could receive a location when both GPS and INTERNET are OFF.

***Note:** You can still get the last received location from any of these providers by using `LocationManager`'s [`getLastKnownLocation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29)* even when the providers are OFF. But this locations are usually outdated ones and are barely of any use.

Comment: Appreciate the reply.I was expecting the same but didn't find a concrete yes/no answer anywhere, so was just making sure. As i mentioned in the last line (was an edit, not sure if you saw it), is there a way to get location on android without internet but GPS on?

Comment: Offcourse Yes. To receive a GPS location, you need not to have internet connectivity. I have personally implemented this in one of my applications.

Comment: But using that(only GPS, without INTERNET) you'll just receive `Location` coordinates (latitude, longitude, accuracy, etc details) and no Address Details. To get the Human Readable Address corresponding to these location coordinates you'll again need to do [Geocoding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) which will require INTERNET! :(

Comment: I want just the latitude and longitude. Can you guide me in the right direction of how to get the location using only GPS? preferably using phonegap (not able to get it using Geolocation API).

Comment: Why you want to use these API's when this could be implemented simply with default `LocationManager`. Here is a very good [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) of Location Tracker. This example shows the use of both GPS and Network location listeners. You can simply ignore the Network part and crop the code for GPS location only once you have completely understood the code.

Comment: I was using these APIs because most of my app is written in javascript using phonegap. But as you said, i will most probably go with native code.

Answer (score 1):

{ enableHighAccuracy: true }
Enabling that option will allow the Android device to get the location even with the WIFI option disabled.